# Redirecting to profile page before login in node.js using passport.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I have 2 pages `http://localhost:3000/pages/auth/login` and `http://localhost:3000/pages/profile`.

When I give the login details it goes profile page but in address bar directly give the /pages/profile.

I want it comes to login page. For authentication I am using passport-local authentication.

Comment: Can you explain well which is the problem please?

Comment: When i login using passport.js it is successfully logged in ad goes to /pages/profile page it is okay. But when i directly give this url http://localhost:3000/pages/profile in address bar it also comes to /pages/profile. It doesn't asking any login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

All passport does is store your session on the server side. On your front-end you need to make calls to the back end to see if your session is still active. The front-end knows nothing on the back-end unless you get some type of response from the back-end.

This is assuming your using expressjs with passport.js

You need to create a function to handle login checks

```html
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/pages/auth/login');

}
```

Your backend route should handle the frontend when it sends a check request

```html
app.get('/pages/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  // send them to the profile page
});
```

Comment: now node.js, passport everything is ok, but i need now angular js authentication

Comment: You can reference to this question that I have answer [Passport Facebook integration with angular-fullstack app not saving user session in angular-fullstack structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841402/passport-facebook-integration-with-angular-fullstack-app-not-saving-user-session/34891220#34891220) . This can definitely help you out with angular authentication. If this helped upvote.